# Protractor with typescript for mouse move

Tags: typescript, protractor

```
it('checking with axis crosshair', () => {
    browser.load( '/demos/chart/axis/axis.html');
    let element1 = element(by.id('container'));
    browser.actions().mouseMove({x: 10, y: 10}).perform();
    browser.compareScreen(element(By.id('container')), 'crosshair');
});
```

I have used above snippet in my code. Even I am changing x and y values, mouse value points to the same location. Can anyone guide me how to use this?